# What is a name for the parts that make up an expression?

Tags: language-agnostic

An expression is a list of functions, variables, constants and operators that can be evaluated and return a result. In the context of expressions, what is the name for each individual item?

Comment: @Brian I thought so too, but looking at his other questions/answers I would be surprised if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A term.

Note however that an expression is also a term when it is used as a term in a larger expression.

Comment: Could operators also be described as terms? The wiki article for mathmatical terms doesn't include them in its example

Comment: No - an expression is a collection of operators and terms. At least - that's how I've always called them - I could be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

An element?

Operators and Operands?

Answer (score 0):

A subexpression, which is of course itself an expression. Some expressions are atomic, i.e. there are no subexpressions. Example are literals, simple names and operators, and so forth.